# How to drop a scheduled job in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created a job named **ENTRY_TIME**

```
BEGIN
      DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
       job_name           =>  'ENTRY_TIME',
       job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
       job_action         =>  'PK_ENTRY_TIME.PROC_ENTRY_TIME',
       start_date         =>  '24-MAY-16 07.00.00 AM America/Chicago',
       repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY',
       end_date           =>  '20-NOV-99 07.00.00 AM America/Chicago',
       auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
      comments           =>  'My new job');
    END;
    /
```

Now I want to drop this job.What query should be used to drop this job **Entry_time** permanently?

Comment: Did you try [`dbms_scheduler.drop_job`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sched.htm#i1000364)? Seems like a good place to start...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.drop_job(job_name => 'ENTRY_TIME');
END;
/
```